# how to make navigable screenshots in wix editor corvid

Tags: velo

currently on wix making a site and want to make images over another
What I desire
a single image on which i can place buttons so that when I press the button accordingly another image is shown and another sets of buttons get enabled and the older ones disabled also as there are 40 images so shorter way is better way
40 images per post and and 10s of posts

I tried doing it using button click
`$w("#element").show("fade");`